# I accidentally typed password into console's "login:" prompt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, login, logging

I accidentally typed my password into the console's "login:" prompt.

Is there any place where the password history could have been saved?

I am running Linux 3.13.0-71-generic, Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Note: There is a similar question marked as answered, but the answer does not address the question itself.

Comment: look in `/var/log/faillog`. by default most linuxes log failed loggin attempts there. you can use the `faillog` executable to read the log and provide parsed output: `faillog -a` or `faillog -u <username>`  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-do-i-display-failed-login-attempt.html

Comment: Look in  `/var/log/auth.log`. Try `cat /var/log/auth.log|grep partofthepassword`. Note better a part of the password, and note the space before the cat . Check  if the part of the password finished in your history, eventually `unset HISTFILE` if you are under bash. Better  you can do `less /var/log/auth.log` and search for the part of the password (so it will be not possible to catch from the `ps`...)

Comment: Thank you. These comments are answers in fact! I would add `/var/log/btmp` to the list of files to be checked. I could find my password in any of them. After some tests, it seems that the failed logging are recorded just if one try to input also a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Linux  can be misconfiged to record usernames of failed login attempts, normally it isn't, because of exactly this known vulnerability. See `man login.defs`,

```
LOG_UNKFAIL_ENAB (boolean)  
Enable display of unknown usernames when login failures are recorded. Note: logging unknown usernames may be a security issue if an user enter her password instead of her login name.
```

Comment: I am impressed by the note being exactly the case presented!